# Qt 5.3 compilation error (missing dll)

Tags: windows, visual-c++, qt5

I'm compiling in `Qt 5.3.1` a small GUI apps under `windows 7 x86`

It fails with error :

> Cannot load language resource clui.dll

The kit used is MSVC2012 opengl, and of course, the dll is installed.

Comment: does this happen only with Qt applications? this seems to be a `cl.exe` error. Are you using Qt Creator or Visual Studio to compile your app?

Comment: Same error, indeed, complete reinstall of msvc, it works now !!